# XML removing items conditionally using xpath

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following xml input:

```
<ns1:sections>
<ns1:section id="sec0001" role="introduction">
<ns1:section-title id="cesectitle0007">Introduction</ns1:section-title>
```

and my goal is to remove introduction. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
for element in root.findall(".//ns1:section", prefix_map):
        print('I am here 2')
        #parent.remove(element)
        role = element.get('role')
        if role == "introduction":
            root.remove(element)
```

**The problem is that it drops some files**. Btw, the prefix map include ns1...

I will be thankful if you can help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: Try finding ".//ns1:section[@roll='introduction']". If it's still removing wrong nodes, print out which ones it's removing and that should tell you why.

Comment: I tried it before, this one removes the whole xml file

Comment: Can you post an example of the input (or a link to it)? This should only select sections where the roll attribute is set to "introduction". It will delete all children of the section which might be causing you a problem.

Comment: And, as @Mike suggested, you add a representative sample of your input xml, please make sure it's well formed.